# dygraph chart validation via ui automation

Tags: automation, protractor, dygraphs

I want to validate dygraph charts using UI automation. Values are displayed on mouse hover.
Value gets displayed under span tag on mouse hover. I want to fetch these values from protractor ui test so i can validate it against a source of truth

Answer (score 0):

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate this is what you need. But you may need help of developers to ask what variable you need to evaluate. But try this first and see what comes back

```
let $elem = element(by.css('dygraph'))
let data = await $elem.evaluate('data')
console.log(data)
```